# How can I change start_urls everyday during cronjob dynamicly?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that has dynamic start_urls. The URL changes every day. Because of the class method, it changes just after deploy or running the server and it stays the same.

***eskisehir.py***

```
class EskisehirSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    now = datetime.datetime.today()- timedelta(days=1)
    now_time = now.strftime("%d.%m.%y")

    name = 'eskisehir'
    allowed_domains = ['www.esktb.org.tr']
    start_urls = ['http://esktb.org.tr/json/gunluk_bulten.php?tarih='+now_time]

    def parse(self, response):
        ###myparser###
```

For example, I deploy my project 30.09.2020 and it supposed to change every day but I recognized yesterday the URL stays the same like `http://esktb.org.tr/json/gunluk_bulten.php?tarih=30.09.20`

So how can I change start_urls every day when the crawler starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need to put the links generator in a separate method. You can also wrap it in @property and refer to it as a property. Here is an example:

```
class EskisehirSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'eskisehir'
    allowed_domains = ['www.esktb.org.tr']

    @property
    def start_urls(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
        now_time = now.strftime("%d.%m.%y")
        return ['http://esktb.org.tr/json/gunluk_bulten.php?tarih=' + now_time]

    def parse(self, response):
        print(f'start_urls is: {self.start_urls}')
        pass
```

Comment: @MuratDemir Glad to hear it. Happy coding!